# Why doesn't my Deferred run the error method?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I have created this simple code to simulate `resolve` , `reject` , `error` :

```
function $http(){
  var core = {
    factory : function (action) {
      var promise = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {

        if (action==='resolve')  resolve({r:'Resolved'});
        if (action==='error')    throw Error("error");
        if (action==='reject')   reject({r:'Reject'});
      });
      return promise;

  } 
  };
  return {
    'simulate' : function(a) {
      return core.factory(a);
    }
  };
}

var callback = {
  success : function(data){
     console.log(1, 'success', data.r);
  },
  error : function(data){
     console.log(2, 'error',data.r);
  },
   reject : function(data){
     console.log(3, 'reject', data.r);
  }
};
```

Now let's invoke them :

```
$http().simulate('resolve')
       .then(callback.success,callback.reject)
       .catch(callback.error); //"success" "Reolved"

$http().simulate('reject')
       .then(callback.success,callback.reject)
       .catch(callback.error); //"reject" "Reject"

$http().simulate('error')
       .then(callback.success,callback.reject)
       .catch(callback.error);//"reject" undefined
```

As you can see both reject/resolve are working.

**Question:**

Why doesn't the :

```
 error : function(data){
     console.log(2, 'error',data.r);
  }
```

Function runs , when I simulate `error`  ?

[**Full Jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/humobe/3/edit)

Comment: It's because you're doing `data.r` but when you throw the error it doesn't exist that's why you're getting undefined as `data.r` doesn't exists, as for why it's calling reject rather than error I don't know. Instead try `data.message` instead of `data.r` for the error one?

Comment: I didnt ask about undefined, I asked about the error func :-)

Comment: Good question. `then(success,reject)` is identical to `then(success).catch(reject)` so I guess it doesn't execute your `catch` if you provide a `reject` to `then`

Comment: @RoyiNamir don't know if this will help but I read it today and I think it may help: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: It seems the error has to be in the resolve or reject functions for the catch to be called.

Comment: @RGraham But it's weird. I don't know if it's going to fail or reject and I need 2 different callbacks

Comment: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hocokimevu/1/edit?js,console,output) Updated jsbin which checks for the error, a messy solution but something along those lines could work. It is a weird behaviour alright.

Comment: @RGraham no it's not.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You're right, I misread the [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) which says it behaves the same as `then(undefined, onRejected)` rather than `then(success, rejected)` - I assume that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - there are cases where you get different behavior - namely in `.then(success).catch(fail)` handles errors in the success handler inside the fail one, `.then(success, fail)` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't the
>
> ```
> error : function(data){
>     console.log(2, 'error',data.r);
> }
> ```
>
> function run, when I simulate `error`?

As per the ECMA Script 6 Promise specifications, when you create a Promise with `Promise` constructor, the promise object created will have two internal slots, `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]` and `[[PromiseRejectReactions]]`, which are actually lists and they will hold all the corresponding fulfill and reject handlers respectively.

When you attach a `then` handler to a promise object, the fulfillment handler will be added to `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]` list and the rejection handler will be added to `[[PromiseRejectReactions]]` list. When the promise is fulfilled, all the handlers in `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]` will be invoked, similarly when the state changes from `pending` to `rejected` all the rejection handlers will be invoked.

In both these cases,

```
$http().simulate('reject')
       .then(callback.success, callback.reject)
       .catch(callback.error);   //"reject" "Reject"

$http().simulate('error')
       .then(callback.success, callback.reject)
       .catch(callback.error);  //"reject" undefined
```

`$http().simulate('reject')` and `$http().simulate('error')` create new promises and when you attach then `then` handler, the `callback.success` and `callback.reject` get added in to the respective reactions list. In both the cases, **throwing an `Error` and rejecting will be treated as rejecting the promise only.** Since there is only one handler in the `[[PromiseRejectReactions]]` for both the cases that is executed. That is why only `callback.reject` is called on both the occasions.

---

What if you have defined the last case, like this

```
$http().simulate('error')
       .then(callback.success)
       .catch(callback.error);
```

Now, the `then` handler doesn't have a onRejected handler. But the important point to be noted here is, all **the `then` handlers will be creating new promises and return them**. So, since the rejection handler is not available with the current `then`, it will create a rejected promise and return it. And **the `.catch(callback.error)` is just syntactic sugar for `.then(undefined, callback.error)`**. The rejected promise's reject reactions list will get the `callback.error` function and that will be invoked, as the promise is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `callback.reject` method is itself handling the thrown error. If you want your `callback.error` to get called then you need to modify the `callback.reject` method to either `throw` the error itself or have it `return Promise.reject(data)`.

Comment: But how can I distinct from `REJECT` to `ERROR` inside the callback.reject. ( without any string search in the result)